# Summing this series??

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let  $T_n$ = $\sqrt{2000^2 - n^2}$

The sum of this series to n terms is $S_n$

Then find $\frac{2}{2000^2}(2000 + 2S_{2000})$ upto $2$ decimal places.

I know in homework questions we do have to write what approach we have tried, but trust me I have tried $\mathbf {EVERYTHING}$ that I could, and can't possibly list them all here. Squaring and summing up $n^2$,the method of differences, a method whose name I forgot in which you multiply and divide by the difference of the two terms and using which you can calculate sum of almost any series except $\mathbf {HP}$(what was it called, pls tell) and on and on and on. Apparently, like Edison I have found 2000 ways how NOT to solve this question,which ironically contains 2000.(I HATE 2000 xD). I asked all my friends. None of them could solve it. So basically this is a question approximately 32 people want to ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use technology to find $S_n$?

Comment: hmmm something to do with $\pi$? :)

Comment: @TimThayer Nope no technology. Cant just tell my teacher that wolfram did it, I know not how. Gotta show the full working.

Comment: @hypergeometric No idea. Are you telling me or asking me. Btw, I fail to see how $\pi$ could possibly come up here??

Comment: What level of math are you taking?

Comment: @TimThayer Well anything till 12th grade would do. Though I am still in 10th, advanced maths is taught to us.

Comment: Have you learned about approximating series? As far as I know, summing square roots doesn't have a closed-form solution.

Comment: @TimThayer Well no the series I have handled till date always tend to have an exact answer. However, the question DID say that answer approximately till 2 decimal places, which I thought was due to the fact that there was $2000^2$ in the denominator, so the expression mentioned divided by $10^6$ gotta have some decimals.  At least thats what I thought. Approximating series?? Could you please post a solution and explain in detail .Maybe I can understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the **Riemann sum** for the unit circle gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 4{n^2}\sum_{r=1}^n\sqrt{n^2-r^2}=\pi$$
Setting $n=2000$ gives
$$\frac 4{2000^2}\sum_{r=1}^{2000}\sqrt{2000^2-r^2}$$
which is the second term of the second expression in the question.

Hence it would appear to be some approximation of $\pi$.

There doesn't appear to be a simple way to compute the summation in the question without using mechanical means.

Wolframalpha returns the first as [$3.14058\times 10^6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(sqrt(2000%5E2-n%5E2))n%3D1%20to%202000) and the second as [$3.14158$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F(2000%5E2)(2000%2B2*sum(sqrt(2000%5E2-n%5E2))n%3D1%20to%202000)).

Comment: "the Riemann sum for the unit circle". Umm what the hell is this??(No offence). I guess this is above 12th grade. But I seriously doubt that something like this would come up in question of series and summations for 10th grade, with difficulty uptil 12th acceptable. Are u SURE that it is the only method??

Comment: Very nice observation!

Comment: @TimThayer - Thanks. Glad you like it :)

Comment: Also, isn't $2000$ a bit small when n tending to infinity gives us $\pi$. I think that it can't be even **approximated** as $\pi$. If n was like 100000 , wouldn't that have been a reasonable approximation??

Comment: @TimThayer Is this what you meant by "approximating series"??

Comment: There are techniques to rewrite the square root in a way that allows us to approximate the answer. You could use a Taylor polynomial, for instance. You could search on the topic "numerical analysis" for more information.

Comment: @Pranav - Draw a circle with radius of $1$. Its area is $\pi\cdot 1^2=\pi$. Take one quadrant of the circle. Slice it into $n$ vertical slices of equal width of $\frac 1n$. The $r$-th slice has height $\sqrt{1-\left(\frac rn\right)^2}$. Multiply these to get the area of the $r$-th slice. Sum from $r=1$ to $n$ to get approx area of one quadrant. Multiply by $4$ to get approx area for whole circle, i.e. an approximation for $\pi$.

Comment: @Pranav - The solution makes an observation that it *seems* to be *some* approximation of $\pi$, not that it *is* a *good* approximation of $\pi$. Just trying to make sense of the question.

Comment: @hypergeometric  Thanks. I think that this question might have crept in accidentally. Not much series and summation in here. Btw, do you know what that method is called??

Comment: @TimThayer Thanks. Do you know what that method is called

Comment: @hypergeometric's method is called a Riemann sum. Riemann sums are the basis for definite integration in Calculus.